# Are private channel states or blocks added to the main ledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, channel, data-storage

I'm trying to understand how data is stored for private channels on Hyperledger fabric. I've read some of the documentation and watched a couple of videos but, I think either data is on the main ledger or it isn't and it kind of  defeats the purpose of ledgers. I've two questions

If a private channel's state changes, is that state change stored in the main ledger's blocks?

If they aren't, is consensus still a thing for channels with few users?

Comment: As a remark, from the accepted answer I guess you were intending to ask about "private data", not "private channel". All channels are private (restricted to the involved organizations and the ordering service). "Private Data" is not a channel, it is a way to share data privately between a subset of the organizations of a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private data is stored only in the private data collections of the peers that have access to those private data collections, and is replicated directly between those peers so is not visible to anyone else. A hash of the private data is stored in the main ledger (channel state) as part of the transaction that updated the private data. See here for details:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you refer with "main ledger".

There is one **[ledger](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/ledger/ledger.html)** per channel. Each ledger consist on a **blockchain** and a **world state**. The blockchain stores all the transactions of the channel organized in blocks. The world state is stored in a DB (SQLite or CouchDB). The world state is the state of the channel resulting from valid chaincode transactions in the blockchain. All peers joined to a channel keep the same ledger for that channel.

The **[ordering service](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/orderer/ordering_service.html)** maintain its own blockchain related to network configuration (ordering service, organizations, etc.). Orderers also keep a copy of every ledger's blockchain (only the blockchain, not the state).

Comment: And there are also private transactions between subsets of the organizations of a channel. These transactions are stored in blocks in the ledger blockchain, but only a hash of the transaction is stored to keep privacy while supporting integrity. The resulting state is stored in a separate DB. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html